# Unix search and replace string that do not match a pattern

Tags: regex, unix

**eg:**

```
abcd |123 |234 |>?987 abc|erf
|urnch |<?utyf |poi 5423 one two lsk|
```

say I have a file full of strings like this.
I want to relace pipe (|) with some other caracter except for pipe with lessthan symbol and question mark `|<?`.

**Result:**
If I want to replacer pipe with dollar ($) then the result should be

```
abcd $123 $234 |>?987 abc$erf
$urnch |<?utyf $poi 5423 one two lsk$
```

except for strings having | all the other piles are replace with dollar.

Answer (score 0):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?:\|[<>]\?)(*SKIP)(*F)|\|/\$/g' file
abcd $123 $234 |>?987 abc$erf
$urnch |<?utyf $poi 5423 one two lsk$
```

Another heck,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?!\|[<>]\?)\|/\$/g' file
abcd $123 $234 |>?987 abc$erf
$urnch |<?utyf $poi 5423 one two lsk$
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this regexp without negative lookahead:

```
\|([^<>])
```

with this replacement text:

```
$$1
```

[**Working Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eG7bA4/1)